# .net core log filtering on certain requests

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In our production environment we have a .net core web service which is load balanced and as a result the load balancer calls a special /health URL every second to check that the service is still up. When the loglevel is set to Info, the log file is quickly filled due to these repeated calls. Seeing as the logs in question come from the .net core framework I can't see how I could filter out these requests without filtering out all requests. Example of the log for this type of request is:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5555/Health
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 1674.6082ms 200
```

Any idea how we could filter these out without also filtering out all other requests ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to use dependency injection to overwrite the default `ILoggerProvider` with one that could inject my own custom `ILogger` for only the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics category and skip logging any events that came from my health check endpoint. This works to filter out the 'Request started' event but the 'Request finished' event uses an object that hides the path of the request in a private field. I drew the line at using reflection to check the path of the request and ended up with this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path != "/api/v1/liveness")
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Request starting {context.Request.Protocol} {context.Request.Method} {context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}{context.Request.Path} {context.Request.ContentLength ?? 0}");
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await next.Invoke();
        Console.WriteLine($"info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Request finished in {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms {context.Response.StatusCode}");
    }
    else
    {
        // liveness probe logic
    }
})
```

It gets the job done because in my appsettings.json I've set the log level for that category to warning:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Warning"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to just filter for a specific category.

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost": "Warning",
        "Default": "Info"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There's more info in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging?tabs=aspnetcore2x), look at the "Log filtering" section.

Comment: OP is asking for a way to filter those logs where he wants logs from WebHost where the route ISN'T /health. They may have a route that's /foo but setting this to Warning would filter out logs for BOTH /health and /foo

Answer (score -5):

Yes, you can set minimum level of logging and it will log only events of this level and higher. Log level priority is:

- Trace
- Debug
- Info
- Warning
- Error
- Critical

I personally use `Error` level to log only errors and critical issues and I do it in this way:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Error()   // <--- this sets the minimum level
                .WriteTo.RollingFile(new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true), 
                    Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "myLog.txt"))
                .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: This only answers the question if you're using SeriLog.